# Force Android to kill service and shedule restart

Tags: android, service, restart

I have a service which can be killed by Android under low memory circunstances. I want to programme it to be able to recover from such event. Is there any method to force android to kill it and shedule it for restart? I ask this because I want a way to test this and not wait for ever to such circunstance happen.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's what you need to do to ensure that your app runs properly? What if the user manually force closes your app and would prefer it to stay that way?

Comment: I dont mind if user want to kill my service. That is ok. But I want a way to test the fact that Android can kill it and restart it when memory conditions improve. What i asked and what I want is a way to test this last condition. I mean a way to force it in my developing box.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with a persistent notification icon in the taskbar, you can set up your service as a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground). When a service runs as a foreground service, Android does not consider it as a candidate to kill when it is low on memory.

You don't need any fancy restart code in this case because the system won't terminate your service.

Comment: Althought set foreground project will not probably kill it, I have seen android killing it. The result is icon contonue showed but service is not running (I am sure because it isn't showed in settimgs/applications/services. Anyway any tip on how to emulate Android killing and reshedule/restart in a development envirobment? Any good programmed service must handle this situation (according to official doc pages, even a foreground service could be killed)